# Prove that the subgroup of rotations $R_n < D_n$ of the Dihedral Group is normal, without reference to the index of a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

**Problem Statement**

> Let $n \geq 3$. Prove that $$R_n = \langle r \rangle = \{I,r,r^{2},...,r^{n-1}\} \subset D_n$$ Is a normal subgroup.

---

Now I know there is a fairly well known fact that any subgroups of index $2$ are normal and in this case we have $\lvert D_n \rvert = 2n$ and $\lvert R_n \rvert = n$ so from Lagrange's Theorem we have $$\frac{\lvert D_n \rvert}{\lvert R_n \rvert} = [D_n : R_n] = 2$$
However this problem is from a section which precedes even the definition of the index of a subset, let alone Lagranges Theorem or the other referenced fact. So I suspect they want us to solve this problem using some other means. I've written up a draft of a proof that I would like to be critiqued. I think it makes sense however I often miss small details and tend not to write the most streamlined proofs as I'm still a relatively nascent proof-writer.

---

**Relations between elements given for $D_n$**

Below are $3$ relations between the elements of $D_n$ given to us during the section. Let  $r^k = r_{\frac{2\pi k}{n}}$ be a rotation by $\frac{2\pi k}{n}$ counterclockwise from the $x$-axis and let $r^{k}j = j_{\frac{\pi k}{n}}$ be a reflection through the line that makes an angle $\frac{\pi k}{n}$ with the $x$-axis (counterclockwise). Then we have:

1. $r^k r^l = r^{k+l}$
2. $r^k j = jr^{-k}$
3. $r^k j r^l j = r^{k-l}$

---

**Proof**

The subgroup $R_n$ is normal iff $\forall a \in D_n$ we have $$aR_n a^{-1} \subset R_n$$ Thus we must show that $\forall r \in R_n$ and $\forall a \in D_n$ $$ar^l a^{-1} \in R_n,\ \text{where}\ 0\leq l \leq n-1$$ Since $R_n$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $r$ we can say $r^l$ is an arbirtrary element of $R_n$. Now all elements of $D_n$ are generated by one of two elements:

- $n$ "rotations" are generated by $\langle r \rangle = \{r^k \mid 0\leq k \leq n-1 \} = R_n$
- $n$ "reflections" are generated by $\langle rj \rangle = \{r^k j \mid 0\leq k \leq n-1 \}$

So first let $a \in \langle r \rangle$. For $k = 0$, $r^0 = I$ the identity element for the group $D_n$ then we have: $$Ir^lI^{-1} = I(r^lI) = Ir^l = r^l \in R_n$$ For $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ we have $$r^kr^lr^{-k} = r^k(r^lr^{-k}) = r^kr^{l-k} = r^{k+l-k} = r^{k-k+l} = r^l \in R_n$$ By the first relation and the fact that addition in the integers is commutative and associative. This makes sense since $R_n$ is a subgroup and hence closed under products.

Now let $a \in  \langle rj \rangle$. Then we have $$(r^kj)r^l(r^kj)^{-1} = (r^kj)r^l(jr^{-k}) = (r^kjr^lj)r^{-k} = (r^{k-l})r^k = r^{k-l-k} = r^{-l} \in R_n$$ By relations $2$, $3$ and $1$ and the fact that the operation in $D_n$ is associative as well as closure of inverses in $R_n$ since $R_n$ is a subgroup and hence a group. Thus $aR_na^{-1} \subset R_n$ and consequently $R_n \vartriangleleft D_n$ $\square$

Comment: What is the given definition of $D_n$?

Comment: @Shaun $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$

Comment: I know *that*, @DavidSheard. I mean: how is it defined? There are many equivalent ways. For example, I'm guessing it's not defined using a presentation.

Comment: The statement '$n$ "reflections" are generated by $\langle rj\rangle=\{r^kj∣0\le k\le n−1\}$' does not make sense. The set of reflections does not form a subgroup, and the group generated by $rj$ is isomorphic to $\{\pm 1\}$, so you need to be careful in how you state things here

Comment: @Shaun in the section "Relations between elements given for $D_n$" OP defines all the non reflection elements explicitly as rotations

Comment: An alternative method which is particularly slick (provided you have already proved that the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup), is to show that $R_n$ is the kernel of the map $D_n\to \{\pm1\}$ which maps each reflection to $-1$.

Comment: You have a couple of typos in your equations (but it was clear that these were oversights, not errors in understanding), and I have submitted an edit which corrects these. Other than those, and the technical point in my comment above, you proof looks  correct to me overall

Comment: @DavidSheard, Couldn't get to my computer for a while. Thanks David for all your suggestions and in particular the point that the set of reflections generated by $\langle rj \rangle$ is not a group. I failed to remember that $\langle rj \rangle$ indicates a cyclic group and not just a set of elements being generated by this one element. I'll need to be more careful about this going forward and will check your edits now. Thanks again for the confirmation as well. I'll give some thought to your alternative proof and see if I can't come up with something